# find out how an LWP request was sent "over the wire"

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

If I send a request with LWP, there is a convenience function `as_string` which tells me what request I just sent.  Very handy, and in truth I have no problems with it.  Except that I just noticed that it is surely lying to me.  For instance, this code:

```
use v5.14.2;
use LWP;
my $response = LWP::UserAgent->new->get('http://user:pswd@example.com/');
say $response->request->as_string;
```

Gives this output

```
GET http://user:pswd@example.com/
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.13
```

But surely the URL was not sent like that!  The library must have parsed out the username and password, and added the appropriate headers, and added a host header, and so on.  Is there an easy way to find out what was actually sent?

Comment: Re "*`as_string` which tells me what request I just sent*", No, it doesn't. LWP::UserAgent meaning LWP::Protocol meaning LWP::Protocol::http meaning Net::HTTP does not use `->as_string`.

Comment: I can't parse what you wrote.  Are you saying that the request eventually ends up at Net::HTTP, which is the one who really writes to the socket, but it writes whatever it wants and doesn't actually tell its caller what it wrote?

Comment: Net::HTTP is the module doing the actual lifting when you use LWP::UserAgent. // Right.

Comment: And does Net::HTTP "save its work" anywhere?  Surely it must, if the answer below is correct?

Comment: No. Maybe some changes end up in the ::Request object, but definitely not all, which is why the answer below said to use a wire sniffer or a dummy server.

Comment: hmm, pity I suppose.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere)<sup>1</sup>, which you can just load to get all the details of both the request as well as the response. The request will be taken right before it's sent over the wire, and the response from when it comes back.

All you need to do is `use LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere` anywhere in your code. If you want more control, the main module [LWP::ConsoleLogger](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger) in that distribution will let you tweak settings easily.

However, this is not the *real* data that goes over the wire. If you want to know what it receives, you need to either monitor the connection with something like `tcpdump` and then take a look at it (which is quite advanced networking stuff), or maybe change the endpoint to your own IP address, or simply `127.0.0.1`, and then use netcat to listen on a specific port.

```
$ nc -l 8080
```

If you send your request to that port, you'll see it in netcat.

[image: screenshot of terminal]

---

<sup>1) Disclaimer: I'm a contributor for that module</sup>

Comment: Neato!  So, no easy way with just the stuff that comes with LWP though?

Comment: @MarkVY there is. Just take a look at the code of LWP::ConsoleLogger. It's quite simple actually. But it will give you the same thing I guess. You'll have a request object that you can convert to a string. I have a talk about how it works at TPCiA but the videos are not up yet.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you did here.  You make sure that every user agent gets created with a some handlers, and then these handlers are no-ops from the point of view of LWP, except that they inspect the request and response very carefully and log whatever they want to.  Neat!

Comment: @MarkVY pretty much, yes. But mine is only the Everywhere part. The rest is all Olaf. Anyway, this module is a great addition for your tool box.

Comment: Got it.  Wait, this is recent!  Like, you just did it this year!  Wow, nice timing I guess.

Comment: @MarkVY yeah, I was bored on a train. Needed something for drop in debugging with LWP, and after I built it I went to IRC to ask if it already existed. It did, so I added my stuff there. Olaf's work is great really.