# Reuse LWP Useragent object with HTTP POST query in a for/while loop

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I am using LWP Useragent to make multiple POST calls with basic Authorization, wherein POST URL parameters are read from a CSV file. Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON 'from_json';
use MIME::Base64 'encode_base64';
use Data::Dumper;

my @assets;
my %data;
my $response;
my $csvfile = 'ScrappedData_Coins.csv';
my $dir = "CurrencyImages";

open (my $csv, '<', "$dir/$csvfile") || die "cant open";
foreach (<$csv>) {
   chomp;
   my @currencyfields = split(/\,/);
   push(@assets, \@currencyfields);
}
close $csv;

my $url = 'https://example.org/objects?';

my %options = (         
        "username" =>  'API KEY',
        "password" => '' );  # Password field is left blank
        
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive=>1);
$ua->agent("MyApp/0.1");
$ua->default_header(
                    Authorization => 'Basic '. encode_base64( $options{username} . ':' . $options{password} )
);
my $count =0;

foreach my $row (@cryptoassets) {
          
          $response = $ua->post(
                     $url,
                     Content_Type => 'multipart/form-data',
                     Content => {
                           'name'=>${$row}[1],
                           'lang' => 'en',
                           'description' => ${$row}[6],             
                           'parents[0][Objects][id]' => 42100,
                           'Objects[imageFiles][0]' =>[${$row}[4]],
                         }
                  );
         
         if ( $response->is_success ) {
             my $json = eval { from_json( $response->decoded_content ) };
             print Dumper $json;
         }
         else {
          $response->status_line;
          print $response;
         }
}
sleep(2);
}
```

Basically, I want to reuse the LWP object. For this, I am creating the LWP object, its headers, and response objects once with the option of `keep_alive` true, so that connection is kept open between server and client. However, the response from the server is not what I want to achieve. One parameter value (`'parents[0][Objects][id]' => 42100`) seems to not get passed to the server in HTTP POST calls. In fact, its behavior is random, sometimes the parentID object value is passed, and sometimes not, while all other param values are passing correctly. Is this a problem due to the reusing of the LWP agent object or is there some other problem? Because when I make a single HTTP POST call, all the param values are passed correctly, which is not the case when doing it in a loop. I want to make 50+ POST calls.

Comment: *"One parameter value (...) seems to not get passed to the server in HTTP POST calls."* - how do you check which parameters get passed? Do you actually check real request or do you just assume that this is the cause of some error your see, but the real cause might actually be something else.

Comment: I didn't check real request and assumed as the abnormal behavior is associated with the specified parameter value while the rest of the parameters are uploaded. Can you tell me how can I check my sent HTTP requests via POST?

Comment: *"Can you tell me how can I check my sent HTTP requests via POST?"* - See [find out how an LWP request was sent “over the wire”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845887/) or [UserAgent Debugging Made Easy](http://www.olafalders.com/2016/09/29/useragent-debugging-made-easy/) on how to do this.

Comment: I found the solution myself. I was passing form data in hashref in POST method. I changed it to arrayref and the problem was solved. I did try LWP Console Logger but the problem was not resolved or maybe I couldn't analyze the HTTP request logs properly. Also, I received "[ REDACTED by LWP::ConsoleLogger.  Do not know how to display multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY-"  and don't know how to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I was passing form parameter data (key/value pairs) using hashref to POST method. I changed it to arrayref and the problem was solved. I read how to pass data to POST method on CPAN page. Thus, reusing LWP object is not an issue as pointed out by @brian d foy.

[CPAN HTTP LWP::UserAgent API](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/GAAS/libwww-perl-5.67/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm)

[CPAN HTTP Request Common API](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/GAAS/libwww-perl-5.67/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm)

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the user-agent object would not be my first suspicion.

Mojo::UserAgent returns a complete transaction object when you make a request. It's easy for me to inspect the request even after I've sent it. It's one of the huge benefits that always annoyed my about LWP. You can do it, but you have to break down the work to form the request first.

In this case, create the query hash first, then look at it before you send it off. Does it have everything that you expect?

Then, look at the request. Does the request match the hash you just gave it?

Also, when does it go wrong? Is the first request okay but the second fails, or several are okay then one fails?

Instead of testing against your live system, you might try httpbin.org. You can send it requests in various ways

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::Util qw(dumper);

my $hash = { ... };
say dumper( $hash );

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$ua->on( prepare => sub { ... } );  # add default headers, etc

my $tx = $ua->post( $url, form => $hash );

say "Request: " . $tx->req->to_string;
```

Comment: I found the solution myself. I was passing form data in hashref in POST method. I changed it to arrayref and the problem was solved. I read it on how to pass data to POST method on CPAN page.

Comment: Thus, reusing LWP object is not an issue.